# URL with no corresponding view

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to get a fileupload working in the same way the existing one does, so I tried to look at how that one works. The original upload functionality just calls a URL (site.com/model/upload/model_id) and then the file that was selected gets saved on the server. Other than that, it renders exactly the same as the model view would (site.com/model/model_id)

Seeing that, I started looking through all server files. There is not a single file called upload, not any other mention of that URL, not even anything in the site controller. The only thing I found was in the modelController:

```
public function actionUpload($id) {
    $model = new Model(); 
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
    if ($model->file) {
        $path = 'uploads/documents/'. $id .'/';
        FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
        $model->file->saveAs($path . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);

    }

    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $this->findModel($id)]);
}
```

How does this work? I tried to replicate it with a copy of this function with a different name, but that then just gives me a page not found error.

The code for the documentupload in the view is this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['upload', 'id' => $model->id]), 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(['style' => ''])->label(false) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Upload', ['class' => 'btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Edit: Solved by adding a boolean parameter to the actionUpload function.

Comment: From what controller are you trying to call this action? `404` gives you, if you call an action which does not exist in the same controller. You need to specify the controller or module in `route` parameter like `site/upload` or similar.

Comment: The codes in the view and controller (views/modelname/view.php and controllers/modelnameController) ar there as I posted them. I have no idea why it works that way, but it does. I can't find any route parameter there.

Comment: Alternatively, I might be able to do what I want if I can change a public variable in the model. Is there any way to do that as part of the activeform?

Comment: Try take a look at how routing can be configured 
 https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing